# ChartJS inside modal/popup window, chart displays 0px height

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, graph, modal-dialog

I'm trying to display a graph inside a modal window when a user clicks a button. The modal window is set to `display: none;` until the button is clicked, which then is set to `display: flex;`

I can take the chart outside of the modal, and it will work fine.

If I change the height of the chart (from 0px) in dev tools, the chart will appear.

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/frasoo/pen/QoxzBV) which demonstrates the problem. Just comment/un-comment the code inside/outside of the modal to see.

The code for the graph is something I took from another codepen example I found.

Another stackoverflow answer provided some help, however I am struggling to implement the solution into my own code. This was the answer I found:

> "It appears that the issue is that the canvas and all its parent nodes cannot have display none at the time the chart call is made so if you are using a chart in a popup you need to show the popup, construct the chart and then hide the popup."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're looking for something like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXKxyZ) , I suppose?

If you check out the `Vue-chartJs` docs you'll see this ([troubleshooting page](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#troubleshooting)):

> If you are using the mixin you need to pass in your options as a prop names options. This is important because the mixin will call chart.js update() method or destroy and render a new chart. If the mixin renders a new chart it calls this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options).

That means that your options need to be saved in the `Vue object`. By doing this, when you call `vue_object.update()` , all the data/options are already in the object.

So, what I changed in your code:

- Declared the `Vue.component` as a `var aux`;
- Added the `options` to the `Vue object` and called `this.options` in the `renderChart()`
- Called `aux.update()` on your `EventListener` for the button.

Hope this helps you out! If you need anything else, you're welcome to ask!

**Note:** Since your chart is very big, it might not be fully visible in the codepen!

Comment: Thank you, this worked mostly as I wanted it to. One question though, do you have any idea why the chart has now lost it's responsiveness? This is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/jlarson/pen/zpVXyb) with the graph (the graph I used).

Comment: Ok,so I've been looking for a while at your code and my guess for the loss of responsiveness is: Is your popup container responsive? ChartJs is loading the chart inside the container, so its responsive to the container. If the container resizes, so should the chart. If it doesn't, then the chart is no longer responsive to the page.

Comment: The container resizes when the chart is not inside it

Comment: It seems to be something to do with how "this.options" has been used. does `options:{
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  },`

ever get called in your piece of code? It seems to be reverting to the default behavior if the options are not found (which is responsive: false, maintainAspectRatio: true)

Comment: Ok, I think I've finally got it! You're correct about `options ` since it was not correctly declared! Ok so, according to [Vue-Chartjs docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html) you need to wrap your chart in a div if you want to have responsiveness. "Responsiveness can then be achieved by setting relative values for the container size".

Comment: What I did: Added an event to the window, for any resize. In that event I changed the css of the wrapper and re-rendered the chart. Also, changed the CSS present in popup-content (changed`width/height` to `max-width/max-height`).
Here is the new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfx1zh7w/29/). Here you can view the result in a [fullpage](http://jsfiddle.net/qfx1zh7w/29/embedded/result/)